# "stop-timeout is not an integer" when generating snap package - why?

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

Based on [the tutorial](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/your-first-snap/), I have created an extremely simple `snapcraft.yaml` which contains the following:

```
name: hectane
version: 1
vendor: Nathan Osman <nathan@quickmediasolutions.com>
summary: Lightweight SMTP client
description: An SMTP client that is extremely easy to configure and use.
icon: icon.png
services:
  hectane:
    description: SMTP daemon
    start: bin/hectane

parts:
  hectane:
    plugin: go
    source: git://github.com/hectane/hectane
```

However, when I attempt to build the snap with `snapcraft`, I end up with the following errors and warnings:

```
Snapping hectane 
Errors
------
 - snappy-systemd_hook_optional_key_stop-timeout_hectane.snappy-systemd
    'stop-timeout' is not an integer
 - snappy-systemd_hook_stop_timeout_hectane.snappy-systemd
    stop-timeout is not an integer
Warnings
--------
 - lint_DEBIAN_extra_files
    found extra files in DEBIAN/: hashes.yaml
 - lint_snappy_unknown
    unknown entries in package.yaml: 'architectures'
hectane_1_amd64.snap: FAIL
Generated 'hectane_1_amd64.snap' snap
```

What do these errors mean and why am I seeing them?

#### Technical Information

**Host:** Ubuntu 15.04
**Architecture:** x86_64
**snapcraft version:** 0.4 (installed via PPA)

Comment: what version of ubuntu-snappy-cli do you have?

Comment: @sergiusens `1.0.1-0ubuntu1`

Comment: the same ppa used to install snapcraft (`ppa:snappy-dev/tools`) has `ubuntu-snappy-cli` `1.5.*` available, care to update and try with that? This is most likely a tools sync issue.

Comment: @sergiusens thanks! I'm not sure why I had an older version installed but once I manually upgraded, everything worked. If you want to repost your comment as an answer, I would be happy to upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`snappy build` and the tool that reviews the resulting `snap` are provided in two different packages developed in separate source repositories but they need to be kept in sync, the most likely cause of this particular issue is that they are indeed **not** in sync. Getting the latest versions of these packages will most likely fix this.

If you've done a release upgrade the *ppa* where the tools are published probably got disabled, you can simply add it again by running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:snappy-dev/tools
```

Then update and upgrade

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Replace `apt-get` for `apt` if you prefer using it.